# future subjunctive conjugation

Tags: verbos, tiempos-verbales

I have learnt how to conjugate the present subjunctive and the imperfect subjunctive.

I can't seem how to conjugate AR, ER & IR verbs for the future subjunctive though?

I have been looking at [comer](https://www.linguasorb.com/spanish/verbs/conjugation/comer) and [hablar](https://www.linguasorb.com/spanish/verbs/conjugation/hablar) on linguasorb & think you take the third person plural preterite then take of "ron" and add the following,

```
yo - re
tu - res
el - re
nos - remos
os - reis
ellos - ren
```

is that correct?

Comment: Check the Real Academia Española website (http://www.rae.es/). When you look for a verb, it shows you the conjugation. For instance: loking for "comer" links you to http://dle.rae.es/?id=9vPNMxG. Clicking in the button labeled *Conjugar* shows the conjugation.

Comment: @user18111 mentions a very useful tool in the comment above, but as a person who loves to right click and open pages in other tabs and windows, this method won't lead you to the conjugation table referred to.  You'll have to left click on the blue button labelled "conjugar."  I recommend anyone reading this give it a try.  It's one of the nicest conjugation layouts I've seen.  Thank you for suggesting this, user18111.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is correct.  The forms of future and past subjunctive are both formed on the same base.  The only difference is that past subjunctive uses **<sup>-ra-</sup>/<sub>-se-</sub>** between the stem and the personal ending, and the future subjunctive uses **-re-**.  As such, for a verb like *nadar* you get *nadare, nadares, nadare, nadáremos, nadareis, nadaren*, and for an irregular like *tener* you get *tuviere, tuvieres, tuviere, tuviéremos, tuviereis, tuvieren*.

You won't generally find much information about the future subjunctive, though, because it's *very* rarely used today (and often used incorrectly at that), and for non-natives could just as well be thought of as not existing.

Comment: Nice answer, +1 from me! // I would have thought that plenty of native speakers happily live their lives without this tense too!  But maybe it's just that when they used it, I didn't catch it.  (Non-native speaker here.)

Comment: @aparente001 in speech if you were to ever hear it, it's probably an affectation.  There are a small number of regions that employ it in speech (rural Canary islands and rural Caribbean) but my guess is that even there it's now dying out with the proliferation of mass media.  It's a shame, it really adds to the expressiveness of the Spanish verb system.